# \vfil and \hfil don't push text to the ends of the box (in article class)

Tags: spacing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

Top \vfil Bottom

\end{document}
```

This yields the following (header and footer excluded):

[image]

From what I've read, \vfil (on its own) adds enough glue to push the subsequent text to the bottom of the box. Using `\vfill` pushes the text all the way to the bottom. AFAIU, when these commands are used on their own, they should behave the same way.

What went wrong?

---

**Update**. A similar effect with `\hfil`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
Left \hfil Right
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Vielen Dank!

Comment: Use `\hfill` for the horizontal case: `\parfillskip` is usually `0pt plus 1fil`, which is the same as `\hfil`, so you need to kill it with a higher order infinite glue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`article` by default uses `\raggedbottom` so the format adds stretch glue at the bottom of each page, your `\vfil` balances that glue so they both stretch the same anount, centring the text in the remaining space. If you use `ll` glue then it expands to the full amount and the `l` glue from `\raggedbottom` is restricted to its natural size of `0pt`.

Comment: Thank you. I've noticed the same thing happening with `\hfil`, but `article` doesn't use `\raggedright` by default. Is there a different reason for this happening?

Comment: @Mirov in any box all glue of the same fill order stretches by the same amount, so if \hfil doesn't stretch as much as you expect then probably something else is adding `l` glue, but it could be anything, given an explicit example it would be easy to say....

Comment: Thank you again. I've updated the question with a simple example.

Comment: @Mirov as egreg says in a comment it is `\parfillskip` essentially the last line of a paragraph _is_ set ragged, so it is exactly the same as the vertical case.